# Difference table for a sequence.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let the sequence $h_0,h_1, ... h_n$  be  defined by $h_n = 2n^2- n+3~(n \geq 0)$. Determine the difference table, and find a formula for summation of $h_0$ through $h_n$

I encountered this problem while working on some exercises on my own through combinatorics. the difference table would be.

3, 4, 9, 18, 31

1,5,9,13

4,4,4,

0,0,

So $h_n = 3\binom{n}{0} + 1\binom{n}{1} + 4\binom{n}{2}$. However, how do I then solve for the formula that sums $h_0$ through $h_n$ and thus finishing the question??

Comment: What is the coefficient of $n$ in the equation for $h_n$?

Comment: What coefficient??

Comment: There is an illegible character in the equation $h_n = 2n^2 - [something]n + 3$, $n \geq 0$.

Comment: coefficient is -1. its actually not showing on my computer. interesting

Comment: It seems to me you are over thinking the question.  You already have a formula for $h_n$.  $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} h_k = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (2k^2 - k + 3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n h_i=3\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{0}+1\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{1}+4\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i}{2}$

$\hspace{1.54 in}\displaystyle=3\binom{n+1}{1}+1\binom{n+1}{2}+4\binom{n+1}{3}=\frac{(n+1)(4n^2-n+18)}{6}.$

using the hockey-stick identity $\sum_{i=r}^n\binom{i}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$.